For or While loop to end table entry
I'm working on a square root table, with a start and end point. However, my points aren't correlating with my table. It's only using the numbers I put for my integers. I need it to use my start number I enter as my first number on the table and the end number as the last number of the table.
On line 24 when I replace the numbers with the words start and end, it gives me an error message. How do I fix this to use my data entry points?
int counter;
int square = 5;
const int maxValue = 15;
//create start and end points for the loop.
Console.WriteLine ("Start: ");
Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("End: ");
Console.ReadLine();

//Print the table headings
Console.WriteLine("Number  Square");
Console.WriteLine("-------------------");

//loop through the numbers 1 through 100
for (counter = 1; counter <= maxValue; counter++)
{
square = counter * counter;
Console.WriteLine("{0}   {1}",  counter, square); 


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically see: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.

Post your code as text in the question itself. Images can't be copied, compiled or tested

Besides, what's the question? You're talking about square roots but print squares. my points aren't correlating with my table what does that mean? The values appear in the correct row.

"On line 24" which is line 24? "it gives me an error message" - what's the error message? Please read https://jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints

Hint: you're printing out Start and End and waiting for a line of text to be entered in the console - but you're not doing anything with that user input.

I need it to use my start number you're never using the strings you read with Console.ReadLine();. This has nothing to do with looping. Use eg var start=int.parse(Console.ReadLine()); and then for (counter=start;....)

It seems the real question is how to use user input. You need to store the input string into some variable before you can use it with. To use the input string as a number you need to parse it, with eg int.Parse:
var start=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Eg :
Console.WriteLine ("Start: ");
var start=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("End: ");
var stop=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

//loop through the numbers 1 through 100
for (counter = start; counter <= stop; counter++)
{
    square = counter * counter;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}   {1}",  counter, square); 
}

Parse will throw an error if the input can't be parsed. You can use int.TryParse to check whether the input is an actual number :
int start=0,stop=0;
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out start))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect value, please type a number");
}

